# Select the Items in Nested set

Tags: mysql, sql, nested-sets

I have the following nested set.

The cat.table:

```
cat.ID Name Lft Rgt
  1     A    1   8
  2     B    2   5
  3     C    3   4
  4     D    6   7
  5     E    9   14
  6     F   10   11
  7     G   12   13
```

OUTPUT: In brackets the count of the items. (In 'A' will count that items, which are in its node, too - B, C and D)

```
 A (7)
 -B (3)
 --C (2)
 -D (1)
 E (3)
 -F (1)
 -G (2)
```

The Items table:

```
ID Cat.ID  Name
1    1     item1
2    2     item2
3    2     item3
4    2     item4
5    3     item5
6    3     item6
7    4     item7
8    6     item8
9    7     item9
10   7     item10
```

If I select the Cat A than I would like to select that items which are in the B, C and D, too. If I select the B, than show the item from B and C. If I select the F than only show from F...
In the Items table I don't have left and right values only tha Cat.ID.

How do I know that if I select the "A" category, which items are in "B", "C" and "D" too?

**EDIT:**
E.g:
If I select B than show the items from B and C (the B is parent of C and C is node of B) - output:

```
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
```

Comment: how are the values calculated?

Comment: tutorial: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/  The calculation after the heading: "Aggregate Functions in a Nested Set"

Comment: @Gery What is your expected output based on these sample data?

Comment: I added an example output to the end

Comment: I can't understand your question. The structure is clear after reading the linked article, but what is the question?

Comment: I need a query which select the (e.g.) "A" category than select that items from the Items table which are not only belongs to the "A" category but the "A", "B", "C" and "D", because the "A" the main category and B, C and D the A's nodes...

Comment: @Gery btw that count table in the middle seem to add no light to the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the *Retrieving a full tree* paragraph of the linked article.

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM Items WHERE cat_id IN (
SELECT cat_id
FROM category AS node,
    category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND parent.name = 'A')
```